# update json list from a list

Tags: python, json

how to update json list / array?

```
j = '''[{"title": "AIG Index", "country": "AUD"}, {"title": "NFP Payrol", "country": "USD"}]'''
    ff = json.loads(j)
add = {"info":"ok"}
print(ff)
```

[{'title': 'AIG Index', 'country': 'AUD'}, {'title': 'NFP Payrol', 'country': 'USD'}]

```
for i in (ff):
  i.update(add)
print(ff)
```

[{'title': 'AIG Index', 'country': 'AUD', 'info': 'ok'}, {'title': 'NFP Payrol', 'country': 'USD', 'info': 'ok'}]

how if i want to upate based on array?
using zip / enumerate not working for json

```
add = [{"info":"ok"}, {"info":"not ok"}]
```

i get error,
**ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required**,
how to get result

[{'title': 'AIG Index', 'country': 'AUD', **'info': 'ok'**}, {'title': 'NFP Payrol', 'country': 'USD', **'info': 'not ok'**}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a builtin zip for python dicts.
But you could simply use something like this:

```
>>> add = [{"info":"ok"}, {"info":"not ok"}]
>>> for count,i in enumerate(ff):
...     i.update(add[count])
... 
>>> ff
[{'title': 'AIG Index', 'country': 'AUD', 'info': 'ok'}, {'title': 'NFP Payrol', 'country': 'USD', 'info': 'not ok'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your data seems simple, you can open you data using *pandas*, do whatever operation you need and then use *to_json()* function to save again.

Here is the example

```
import pandas as pd
j = '''[{"title": "AIG Index", "country": "AUD"}, {"title": "NFP Payrol",  "country": "USD"}]'''
df1 = pd.read_json(j)
df1['ok'] = ['ok','not ok']
df1.to_json('file.json')
```

Comment: I added how I'd do it in pandas just for reference to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

```py
import json

ff = json.loads(
    '''[{"title": "AIG Index", "country": "AUD"}, {"title": "NFP Payrol", "country": "USD"}]''')

add = [{"info": "ok"}, {"info": "not ok"}]

for i, f in enumerate(ff):
    f.update(add[i])
```

Or you can use list comprehension:

```py
ff = [dict(f, **a) for f, a in zip(ff, add)]
```

Comment: working like a charm . thank you very much 